# How to order by Month?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried `factor()` function in `aes`, but it did not work for ordering the months from January to December. How do I fix the code? Thanks.

```
LC10 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/Final Project/LC1.xlsx", sheet = 9)

ggplot(data=LC10, aes(x=factor(Month), y = Chargeoffs9))+ 
       annotation_custom(grob1,xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.03, ymax = 0.10) + 
       geom_bar(aes(fill=Month), stat="identity", alpha = 0.6) + 
       scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) + 
       theme_bw(base_size = 16) + theme_classic() +
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) + 
       ggtitle("Month of Loans vs. Charge-Offs") + 
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position="none") + 
       labs(x = "Month of Loans", y="Percent of Charge-Offs")
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: In your `aes` statement, try changing to `x=factor(Month,levels=month.name)`.  `month.name` is a list of months built in to R (in the right order!).

Comment: You need to have factored x-labels considered as ordered. Try use : `factor(Month,levels=month.name, ordered = T)` or `ordered(Month,levels=month.name)` (it is the same).